# Connecting to SQL Server 2012 (using Windows auth) via powershell Enter-PSSession

Tags: sql-server, authentication, sql-server-2012, powershell-2.0, windows-authentication

Hope you can assist me with an issue I am facing. This is a lengthy one to provide context. In short, my Windows auth access to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database fails as it appears to be trying to access the database as 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' and not the current user.

Here's my scenario: server farm with multiple servers running standalone SQL Server databases on which a number of PowerShell scripts need to be run, which connect to the databases and run some queries & based on the queries, make some updates to some database tables. We're failing at Windows auth login to the database (which works fine with SQL Server Mgmt Studio v10).

It looks something like this:

1. win7pc PS C:> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName winsvr2k8r2
2. [winsvr2k8r2]: PS c:\users\svs_acct1>
3. [winsvr2k8r2]: PS c:\users\svs_acct1> Set-Location C:

   - NB: there is a script directory that is part of the `$env:PATH` set in the profile
4. [winsvr2k8r2]: PS c:\users\svs_acct1> . .\users\svs_acct1\bin\Run-AdminTasks

**Script output**

```
Loading AD module ...  
 Setting Global Variables ...  
 I am user: domreff1\dbappuser  
 Initiating DB Connection using windows auth to: sTango @ hgr23992\atr77504  
  with connect string ...  
   Data Source=hgr23992\atr77504;Initial Catalog=sTango;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

**ERROR**

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'."
>   At C:\users\svs_acct1\bin\Run-AdminTasks:21 char:20
>   + $SqlConnection.open <<<< ();
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

The relevant DB connection elements in the script:

```
$SQLServer = "hgr23992\atr77504";  
$SQLDBName = "sTango";  
$SQLDBUser = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name;  

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection  
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$SQLServer;Initial Catalog=$SQLDBName;Integrated Security=SSPI"  
$SqlConnection.open();
```

I have trawled through various posts and tried connection string a number of different ways e.g.

```
Data Source=$SQLServer;Initial Catalog=$SQLDBName;Integrated Security=[Yes|True|SSPI]
```

with no joy.

Any ideas on what the issue may be and why the DB connection seems to be reflecting a different context/user to what I am running the script as?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is kerberos auth and the missing delegation of the token.

You could enable CredSSP auth for powershell (on client & server side). Please do this only over SSL otherwise you're vulnerable for an MITM.

check
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309365(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you marc_s for the edits.

@Neroon, thank you for your suggestion. I am trying to get the relevant admins to make the required config changes to allow this to be tested, but may not be permitted to complete this action in its current format. If I don't succeed in getting this past the admin & security teams in the next week, I'll seek another avenue/approach. Much appreciated

Comment: Just a quick update. I was unable to test this in our current environment [internal policy or politics, etc.] and  chose a different method (read dirty hack) to achieve what was required.